# How to calculate the integral $I=\int\limits_0^1\frac{x^n-1}{\ln(x)} \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

How can we calculate this integral:

> $$I=\int\limits_0^1\frac{x^n-1}{\ln(x)}\,\mathrm dx$$

I believe that integral is equal to $\ln(n+1)$, but I don't lnow how to prove it.

Comment: Why do you care about this integral and what makes it "very hard"?

Comment: I believe that integral equal to ln(n+1), but I don't lnow how to prove it.

Comment: This is a classical problem that can be easily solved using Feynman's trick. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/827584/201168).

Comment: Can you show,please?

Answer (score 5):

One may observe that $$\frac{x^n-1}{\ln x}=n\int_{0}^{1}x^{nu} du$$ plugging it in your initial integral, applying Fubini's theorem, gives
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^n-1}{\ln x}dx= n\int_0^1\!\!\frac{1}{nu+1}du=\int_0^1\frac{(nu+1)'}{nu+1}du=\ln(n+1).
$$

Comment: @OliviwrOloa I took the liberty of fixing a typo - a missing $n$ in the exponent of the first integrand.  I hope that you don't mind my doing so.

Answer (score 4):

If we replace $x$ with $e^{-t}$ we are left with:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-(n+1)t}}{t}\,dt = \log(n+1) $$
by [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

Comment: You would need to prove that the integral converges though.

Comment: @user17762: that is quite trivial since the integrand function is positive, bounded on $[0,1]$ and less than $e^{-t}$ on $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I answered a problem or two on Frullani ... development and application.  And here is yet another! It's a really neat equality.

Comment: I corrected the dummy differential in the integral from $x$ to $t$ in order to match the dummy variable of the integrand.

Answer (score 2):

Let: $$I(n)=\int_0^1\dfrac{x^n-1}{\ln x}dx$$
Then: \begin{align}I'(n)&=\dfrac{d}{dn}\int_0^1\dfrac{x^n-1}{\ln x}dx=\int_0^1\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}\left[\dfrac{x^n-1}{\ln x}\right]dx\\
&=\int_0^1 x^n dx=\left.\dfrac{x^n+1}{n+1}\right\vert_0^1\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n+1} \end{align}
Therefore: $$I(n)=\int I'(n)=\ln(n+1)$$

Comment: The OP asked for a definitive integral so you might want to compute $C$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $(a^x)'=a^x\cdot log(a)$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$x^a = e^{a\log x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(a \log x)^k}{k!}$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{x^a-1}{\log(x)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^k \log^{k-1}(x)}{k!}$$
Make use of the  fact that
$$\int_0^1 \log^m(x) dx = (-1)^m m!$$
Hence, we obtain
$$\dfrac{x^a-1}{\log(x)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^k}{k!} (-1)^{k-1} (k-1)! = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{a^k}k =  \log(1+a)$$

Note that the above derivation is only valid when $a \in (-1,1)$. For $a\geq1$, it is easy to show by similar method that
$$I(a) - I(a-1) = \log(1+1/a)$$
Since $I(a) = \log(1+a)$ on the interval $[0,1]$, we can now conclude that
$$I(a) = \log(1+a)$$
for all $a \geq -1$.